# Labelled "continue" doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, primes, labelled-break

Just started learning java and I can't understand what's wrong with my code. *PrimeIterator* is supposed to generate infinite amount of prime numbers (starting from a number 3) but when I print the output I get: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 etc.

```
public class Prime {

    PrimeIterator iter = new PrimeIterator();

    private class PrimeIterator implements java.util.Iterator<Integer>
    {
        int numb = 1;

        public boolean hasNext() 
        {
            return true;
        }

        public Integer next() 
        {
            nextCandidate:
            do{
                numb += 2;
                int numbSqrt = (int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(numb);

                for (int i = 3; i <= numbSqrt; i = i+2)
                {
                    if (numb % i == 0)
                    {
                        continue nextCandidate;
                    }
                }
            }while(false);
            return numb;
        }

        public void remove() {}
    }

    void printPrimes()
    {
        System.out.print(2);
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.print(", " + iter.next());   
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to use labelled "continue" statement for my do-while loop. However my intuition tells me that I use it incorrectly.

Comment: You know 9 and 15 aren't prime numbers, right?

Comment: maybe I'm missing it, but it doesn't look like you're printing output at all

Comment: Instead of continue I would recommend breaking. or return false

Comment: Please everyone, he has labeled his `do` loop with the `nextCandidate` label. The continue will affect the outer loop.

Comment: Your code won't compile, because it's missing `void remove()` as specified by `Iterator`. It would also be nice to have the `main` function so we don't have to create it in order to help you.

Comment: @KRUKUSA
Neither of these works. Also, you can't return false in that method.

Comment: @aliteralmind
Oracle documentation told me that remove is optional. Rest of the code coming right up.

Comment: Start your for loop at 2 instead of 3 because 2 is a prime number.

Comment: *Removing an element* is optional, but *implementing the `remove` function* is still required. Implement it to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` (and document it as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is with the `while(false)` continuation condition. Being a `do while(false)` statement, this means that it can never loop more than once. That is, when you try to jump the execution to the labeled statement, it won't cycle again through the `do while` because the continuation condition (`false`) is not validated, even if you think that `continue` will make the execution loop again.

So it will never increment `numb` more than once per `next()` method execution.

I'd do something like the following:

```
nextCandidate:
do{
    numb += 2;
    int numbSqrt = (int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(numb);

    for (int i = 3; i <= numbSqrt; i = i+2)
    {
        if (numb % i == 0)
        {
            continue nextCandidate;
        }
    }
    break;

}while(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains my issue!

Comment: Ok. Please also note the observation @Sam I am posted regarding truncation of `sqrt` (point 3. in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems that I see

1. You're not even printing output.
2. `(int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(5)` will end up truncating to `2`.  You should add 1 to your square root, since it's a problem if you don't iterate enough, but it's not a problem if you iterate more than you need to.
3. when you do find a prime number, your `for` loop will end, and `while(false)` will terminate the do-while loop

Comment: @AndreiNicusan you're right.  I was afraid that if `i` was 4, than it would say that 4 was prime, but then again, `i` will never be `4`

Comment: I wanted to increase my numbers by 2 to kinda optimize the whole thing. I couldn't nicely implement generating number 2 in my PrimeIterator subclass.

Comment: actually, not what I think about it more, the square root thing won't actually end up being a problem either

Comment: @Sam, I think you may have produced a full trifecta of wrongness.  He produces output through an iterator that can be printed or otherwise used by the caller (a more flexible approach than directly printing).  The sqrt truncation is a feature, not a bug.  Your third point describes the desired behavior rather than a problem.